# Scroll bar in IOS app development UI not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, cordova

IOS app development with phone-gap.
Myindex.html code(related) is as follows:-

```
    <script type="application/javascript" src="iscroll.js"></script>
    <script>

        var myScroll;
        function loaded() {
            setTimeout(function () {
                       myScroll = new iScroll('edit');
                       }, 100);
        }
        window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);
      ..
      ..
      </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    #toolHome,#toolEdit,#toolSetting,#toolMessage{
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 10%;
        display:table;
        z-index:20;
    }
    </style> 


</head>
<body id="bd">
    <div id="toolEdit" class="toolbar">
        <h1 id="pageTitle">Edit</h1>
        <a id="preButton" class="button" onclick="home()">Message List</a>
    </div>
    <div id="edit" title="Edit" ></div>
    <div id="bottomButtons" style="position:fixed;top:90%;width:100%;display:table;height:11%;z-index:20;display:none;"><a class="redButton buttomButton" style="width:22%;position:relative;top:4px" align="left" onclick="deleteList()"><img src="iui/t/default/trash.png" >&nbsp;Delete</a></div>
 </body>
```

So here, div 'toolEdit' contains header section. Div 'edit' contains the content part which needs to be vertically scrollable when content exceeds the available space.div 'bottomButtons' is the footer which contains delete button. z-index has been given for both header and footer, so the content slides below both header and footer. 
    The problem is, the bottom part of the content when it is tried to scroll up(residing below footer) does'nt scroll and if tried takes the footer with it, making it blank.

Tried using iscroll plugin(shown in the code) also, but it is not helping.
    Any suggestions will be appreciated.
    Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the CSS of `#edit`? If you want an element to be vertically scrollable, you need to give it a height explicitly. I'd remove `position: fixed;` from the tools and add `#edit { height: 80%; overflow: scroll; }`

Comment: I did what u told..but it dint work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phonegap 2.8 Position: fixed is not working properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131487/phonegap-2-8-position-fixed-is-not-working-properly)